# Proving sets of regular expressions and context free grammars are decidable

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, undecidability

Consider below languages:

1. $L_1=\{<M>|M$ is a regular expression which generates at least one string containing an odd number of 1's$\}$
2. $L_2=\{<G>|G$ is context free grammar which generates at least one string of all  1's$\}$

Its given that both above languages are decidable, but no proof is given. I tried guessing. $L_1$ is decidable, its a set of regular expressions containing

- odd number of $1$'s, or
- even number of $1$'s and $1^+$ or
- $1^*$

So we just have to parse regular expression for these characteristics. Is this right way to prove $L_1$ is decidable?

However, can we have some algorithm to check whether given input CFG accepts at least one string of all 1's? I am not able to come up with and hence not able prove how $L_2$ is decidable.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: The problem did not talk about intersection of regular and context free languages, but whether they accept certain kind of words independently.

Comment: The first listed dup (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80713/what-is-the-complexity-of-deciding-if-the-intersection-of-a-regular-language-and) seems to address exactly that, and also explains why intersection is relevant.